# Can I get ngparams pagination method value other than `data` variable [ Angularjs 1.x ]

Tags: angularjs, pagination

I'm using `ngParams` for mytable filtering and sorting. Now, in a case, I've two paginated content on a same page and same controller (but having different methods). Every pagination content is assigned to `data` variable. Thus, the new result is overriding the previous data (means the old paginated content, got from the first method is overrided by the new paginated content, got from the next method).

Comment: what are you asking?

Comment: `ngParams` has a method `getData()` in which we can write our own code to get data from the API. Now, the returned result is always assigned in the `data` variable, while I want to override this variable name and update the variable name as per my own choice. The reason of this, I've used same method in a single page two times and the previously got value is overrided with the new value. Thus, I'm not able to show my data in the html file. Thanks.